# Probability of each event happening at least once, with replacement

Tags: probability

Let's say we have a bag of m objects. We draw uniformly at random an object from the bag (with replacement) and repeat this n times. What is the probability of all objects having been drawn at least once. Obviously, if n < m then the probability is 0. I am not sure how to best tackle this problem for n >= m. It seems to me that the inclusion-exclusion principle would work, but I am having a hard time simplifying the big formula.. Is there any other way?
Thank you.

Comment: You can think of this as the probability for a sum of independent geometric variables to be at most $n$. See [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: You could also approach this problem with Markov Chains. Set $X_0=0$ and, for $k\geq 1$, let $X_k$ denote the number of *distinct* items observed immediately after sampling the $k^{\text{th}}$ item. Clearly $\{m\}$ is an absorbing state. You're trying to find the probability of reaching this absorbing state after $n$ steps when you start at state $\{0\}$.

Comment: With regards to "simplifying the big formula" created by inclusion-exclusion... [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) do that.  Whether you consider this "simplifying" it or just masking it... The probability ends up being $\dfrac{{n\brace m}m!}{m^n}$.  Why you might consider this just "masking it" is because one of the formulas to calculate stirling numbers of the second kind is precisely that big formula you are trying to avoid.  There do exist alternatives (e.g. recurrence) but these might not be easier.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable answers, I will try all these approaches :)